# l3regex: Regular expression for a new line symbol \\

Tags: line-breaking, expl3, latex3, l3regex

How to set regular expressions for a character `\\` correctly? MWE below produce unwanded extra space character between words with  `\c{\\}`.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\ttl}{ m }
{
    \tl_set:Nn \l_title_tl {#1}
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {#1}
    \regex_replace_all:nnN { \c{\\} } { } \l_tmpa_tl
    \tl_use:N  \l_tmpa_tl
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\ttl{One \\ Two}

One Two
\end{document}
```

Users may produce `\ttl{One\\ Two}` or `\ttl{One \\ Two}`. And I want just remove `\\` and join words by single space.

[image]

Comment: In `One \\ Two`, there is one space token before ``\\`` and one after. Seems to be working as designed.

Comment: @frougon Users may produce `\ttl{One\\ Two}` or `\ttl{One \\ Two}`. And I want just remove `\\` and join words by single space.

Comment: urelated to your main question but a note that your title is misleading. In almost all standard contexts `\\ ` does not end a paragraph, it forces a new line while keeping the current paragraph. (like Html `<br>` not like `html> `</p>`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `One \\ Two`, there is one space token before `\\` and one after; therefore, the regexp replacement is correct (`\tl_show:N \l_tmpa_tl` clearly shows two consecutive space tokens remaining in `\l_tmpa_tl` after the replacement).

Given your stated use case, I propose the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \ttl { m }
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {#1}
    \regex_replace_all:nnN { \ * \c{\\} \ * } { \ } \l_tmpa_tl
    % \tl_show:N \l_tmpa_tl % for checking
    \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\ttl{One \\ Two}

One Two
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Spaces are not ignored after `\\`, so with your input `\ttl{One \\ Two}` you just remove `\\`, but the two space tokens remain. Besides, if the user types `\ttl{One\\Two}` you'd get no space.

So you want to transform a sequence of `\\` preceded or followed by spaces into a single space.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\ttl}{ m }
  {
    \sergio_ttl:n { #1 }
  }

\tl_new:N \l__sergio_ttl_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \sergio_ttl:n
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l__sergio_ttl_tl {#1}
    \regex_replace_all:nnN { \s* \c{\\} \s* } { \  } \l__sergio_ttl_tl
    \tl_use:N \l__sergio_ttl_tl
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\ttl{One \\ Two}

One Two

\end{document}
```

[image]

If I do `\tl_analysis_show:N` instead of `\tl_use:N`, I get

```
The token list \l__sergio_ttl_tl contains the tokens:
>  O (the letter O)
>  n (the letter n)
>  e (the letter e)
>    (blank space  )
>  T (the letter T)
>  w (the letter w)
>  o (the letter o).
```

If you expect that your users might have `\\*` or `\\[<dimen>]` or the combination thereof, change the internal function into

```
\cs_new_protected:Nn \sergio_ttl:n
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l__sergio_ttl_tl {#1}
    \regex_replace_all:nnN { \s* \c{\\}\s*(\*\s*|\[.*\])* \s* } { \  } \l__sergio_ttl_tl
    \tl_use:N \l__sergio_ttl_tl
  }
```

This would also cover all the following cases:

```
\ttl{One \\ Two}
\ttl{One \\[1ex] Two}
\ttl{One \\ [1ex] Two}
\ttl{One \\* Two}
\ttl{One \\ * Two}
\ttl{One \\*[1ex] Two}
\ttl{One \\* [1ex] Two}
\ttl{One \\ * [1ex] Two}
```

and of course all those with no space after `One` or before `Two`.

Answer (score 3):

The following definition ignores the space after `\\` because the `#2` of the `\ttlA` is unseparated parameter: TeX ignores spaces in this case.

```
\def\ttl#1{\ttlA#1\\\end}
\def\ttlA#1\\#2{#1\ifdim\lastskip=0pt \space\fi\ifx\end#2\else\afterfi{\ttlA#2}\fi}
\def\afterfi#1#2\fi{\fi#1}

\ttl{One \\ Two}

\ttl{One\\ Two}

\ttl{One \\Two}

\ttl{One\\Two}

One Two

\bye
```

All these examples gives the same result: single space between One Two.

Comment: Thank you. By I prefer realize it in LaTeX3

Comment: @sergiokapone I prefer TeX primitive solution because it does not depend on LaTeX. And you can see that this solution is very simple and if tracingall is activated then you can see that my solution does much less operations. And it is closer to TeX basis. All problems discussed here is simply TeX.

Comment: I have nothing against your answer and against plain TeX. It's just part of code  that's already been written in LaTeX3